# Download, save and execute JS file in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios

1. Is it possible to download a Javascript file from a remote server, save it to the local disk area of my app and then use that file in code to execute it and show it in a web view? That would make it possible to update the content of my app without submitting any new version to the App Store.
2. Does Apple allow it? I.e even if its programmatically possible, will it pass the App Store review?

3 & 4: Same question for Android and Google Play Store.

Comment: Apple requires to review each version of the app. They do not like you being able to update the app bypassing the review process

Comment: `Is it possible` yes. `Does Apple allow it?` does not relate to application development, and is a question for lawyers, not developers. `Same question for Android and Google Play Store.`: `Is it possible` yes. `Does Google allow it?` yes if you declare your app as a web browser. Same thing - the question is for lawyers, not for developers.

Comment: From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) 2.4.5(iv) and 2.5.2, an application can't download or install additional code which changes the functionality, but if your app doesn't have any functionality beyond a repackaged website (4.2), it will probably be rejected outright.

Comment: 1. Yes it is possible through a `WKWebView` or `JSContext` 2. Does Apple allow it depends on your implementation...